# How to loop multiple page on selenium python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Right now my this code able to click on every single product of this page "https://www.daraz.com.bd/audio/?page=1&spm=a2a0e.home.cate_2.2.49c74591NNpWDU%27" which taking me to product details page of each item. Can anybody tell me how I will loop multiple pages such as  page2, page3, page4? here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#argument for incognito Chrome
option = Options()
option.add_argument("--incognito")


browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)

browser.get("https://www.daraz.com.bd/audio/?page=1&spm=a2a0e.home.cate_2.2.49c74591NNpWDU%27")


# Wait 20 seconds for page to load
timeout = 20
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='c16H9d']")))
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
    browser.quit()


soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")

product_items = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"data-qa-locator": "product-item"})
for item in product_items:
    item_url = f"https:{item.find('a')['href']}"
    print(item_url)

    browser.get(item_url)

    item_soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
    # Use the item_soup to find details about the item from its url.
    container = item_soup.find_all("div",attrs={"id":"container"})
    for items in container:
        title = items.find("div",{"class":"pdp-product-title"})
        print(title)



browser.quit()
```

**now it getting information only from page1. I want it will also collect information from other pages such as page2,page3,page4,page5**

Comment: Each page has a pagination object to take you to the previous/next page, etc.

Comment: how I will do it? please explain with code if possible. Thanks for  your comment

Comment: @FarhanAhmed Stack Overflow is not a substitute for guides, tutorials or documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you can see in website when you click on page 2 in the URL the only thing that changes is page number so this can be easily done by loops.
for a better code you can make a variable called url and change that for each page:

```
for page_num in range(1, 10): # change the range as you want to
    url = "https://www.daraz.com.bd/audio/?page={}&spm=a2a0e.home.cate_2.2.49c74591NNpWDU%27".format(page_num)
```

and put the rest of code inside this loop (except for the last line)

Comment: Thanks Kurosh Ghanizadeh. It worked. Can please tell me how to get output in a csv file? what code I need to be write to get output?

Comment: I haven't worked too much with CSV so I suggest just read some documentation. It's not a complicated thing you can work with it easily